# How to change divider color option menu item?

Tags: android

I want to change default divider color of my option menu, so can give me some suggestion or technical?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Its working for me in Navigationmenu.
This below line is mandatory.

```
<item name="android:listDivider">@color/white</item>
```

This is your style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:listDivider">@color/white</item>
    </style>
//This is ur menu item.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/m_profile"
            android:title="@string/my_profile" />
        <group android:id="@+id/my_id">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_coming"
                android:icon="@drawable/m_coming"
                android:title="@string/comingsoon" />
        </group>
 </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by setting theme to your popup menu

use below code in your style.xml file in res folder

```
 <style name="MyThemePopup" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">2px</item>
        <item name="android:divider">#F00</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/opaque_black_color_dark</item>
    </style>
```

above code is for creating theme where   `<item name="android:divider">#F00</item>` is use for setting color to divider

after that you can set created theme to your activity in which popup menu is present through manifest file

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.android.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyThemePopup" />
```

hope this code will help you to achieve your requirement happy coding :)

Comment: Also adding the MyThemePopup won't make any dividers appear

Answer (score 0):

Does nothing for me, maybe because of the appCompat version?

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/ucc_blue</item>
</style>
```

It doesn't matter if i put it in the MyActionBar style or in the AppTheme style both won't work. But setting the divider height does make my OptionMenu scrollable....

Maybe it doesn't work because they are subMenuItems?

Answer (score 0):

add this item to the app theme:

```
<style name="theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>
</style>
<style name="MyDropDownListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who have not found the answer yet for this problem, this is how it worked for me and hope it will work for you as well:

```
        <style name="PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/background_medium_gray</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/BackgroundGray</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>

    Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.PopupMenu);
    final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view);

    final MenuInflater menuInflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
```